# HTTP File download with spaces

Tags: http, download, filenames, spaces

Can a file download be created with the right HTTP headers that will cause the spaces to not be replaced or stripped? This is for email attachments which often contain spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just quote it.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file name with spaces.ext"
```